# Python data visualization: too small value to be visible - how to solve?

Tags: python, bar-chart, visualization

Here is dataset, i have:

| Source | All Leads | Not Junks | Warms | Hots | Deals | Weighted Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| web | 281316 | 269490 | 10252 | 2508 | 1602 | 4376.5 |
| telesales | 30458 | 29732 | 431 | 138 | 85 | 316.2 |
| networking | 4249 | 4195 | 763 | 547 | 476 | 539.1 |
| promos | 1356 | 1308 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 10.8 |

I visualized it:

```
df.plot.bar()
```

And got this output:

[image]

Some columns got too small values, so that they are not visible, how can tackle this problem?

Setting bigger figure size isn't useful, it makes chart bigger, but columns ratio is still the same, so nothing changes

Any ideas how to make it look more sophisticated? Or maybe i should try different type of chart? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try df.plot.bar(logy=true), but it's going to make useful interpretation of it messy. A Sankey diagram would probably be a better fit for showing how the data breaks down in each category.

Comment: +1, applying log transformation might help in this scenarios, but you need to know what you are trying to show in the graph. Is it to show the actual comparison or relative comparison of each category?

Comment: @Thu Ya Kyaw, actual comparison

Answer (score 3):

Seaborn comes out a *little* nicer, but takes some transformation to produce the same type of output:

```
import seaborn as sns

df2 = df.melt('Source').rename(columns={'variable': 'Category', 'value': 'Values'})

sns.barplot(x='Source', y='Values', data=df2, hue='Category')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Seaborn Barplot]

Or with `log=True`

[image: log of it]